# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) while using contact form 7

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7

I am using Contact Form 7 plugin in a wordpress website to deal with the "contact us" email.
But I am getting this error while clicking the submit button: 
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
My code looks like this: [image]

I have used jquery to replace the input[type=submit] with a button.
The problem is that when i click the button it displays in the console that error. It sends the email if the fields are filled currectlly, but it also is not displaying any message that the email has been send, and is not displaying the error messages and any validation message if there is any error or any unfulfilled validation.

What is the problem?

Comment: What do you mean, "replace submit with a button" ?  You mean, instead of input type="submit" you made it a `<button>`

Comment: @HowardE, yes. I had to put a span element inside the button, for the style purpouse, so I  used something like this:     $('#contact-form .wpcf7-submit').replaceWith("<button type='submit' class='wpcf7-form-control wpcf7-submit butn butn-bg disabled'><span>Send Message</span></button>");

Comment: Why are you doing this?  You can add the classes to the submit button.

Comment: @HowardE, but I can't add a <span> inside it, for that.

Comment: And why do you need a span? What is it doing for you?